# Understanding the passage: for $0<x<1$ we have $\frac{1}{x}>1$ so $x^{1/x}<x$ (the signs reverse since $\log{x}<0$)

Tags: calculus, inequality

There is a passage in the middle of a solution to a problem in Spivak's *Calculus* that says

> For $0<x<1$ we have $\frac{1}{x}>1$ so $x^{1/x}<x$ (the signs reverse
> since $\log{x}<0$).

What is being done in this passage. What does it mean that "the signs reverse since $\log{x}<0$"?

For context, this is in the middle of the very long problem 26 in Ch. 22, "Infinite Sequences", and is simply a step that I don't quite understand.

Comment: Insert $\frac{1}{x} \log x < \log x$ between $\frac{1}{x} > 1$ and $x^{1/x} < x$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $1<\frac{1}{x}$, and $0<x<1$.

Since we know that $\log x<0$, by multiplying both sides by $\log x$ we get $\frac{1}{x}\log(x)<\log(x)$, since $\exp()$ is increasing we get $\exp(\frac{1}{x}\log(x)) = x^{\frac{1}{x}}<\exp(\log(x)) = x$.